# Mi archivo Jar no prosigue con todas las interfacez graficas

Tags: java

```
public Datos(){
setLayout(null);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setTitle("Pantalla principal");
getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255,0,0));
setIconImage(new 
ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/Icon.png")).getImage());
Bienvenido usuarioBienvenido = new Bienvenido();
nombreAdmin = usuarioBienvenido.nombre; /*Esta es la linea 25 del codigo de la tercera interfaz (clase Datos)*/

/*Esto es de la primera interfaz(clase Bienvenida) donde se modifica la variable y obtiene el valor escrito*/                                      
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource() == boton1){
    nombre = usuario1.getText().trim();
        if(nombre.equals("")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debes ingresar un nombre.");
          } else {
            Terminos termino = new Terminos();
            termino.setBounds(0,0,600,360);
            termino.setVisible(true);
            termino.setResizable(false);
            termino.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            this.setVisible(false);
        }

    }
}
```

`[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy siguiendo un curso de Java y el final es empaquetar tres interfaces graficas en un archivo Jar en cierto orden, todo bien, pero a cuando termino de empaquetar y abro el archivo Jar no prosigue a la 3ra interfaz grafica, llega a la primera, todo bien, llega a las segunda(que es la que se muestra en la imagen) y para seguir tengo que darle click al cuadrito y despues al boton para llevarme a la ultima interfaz, pero no me lleva y me sale un mensaje error en el CMD (Que para ser sincero no entiendo)

Mi pregunta es: ¿Por que sale ese error?
¿Tengo que modificar algo en el codigo?
Lo eh hecho varias veces y los comandos del CMD los eh puesto bien.
Cualquier ayuda se agradece.

Comment: Al parecer tienes un error a la hora de cargar un ImageIcon. Para ofrecer mejor solución añade el código.

Comment: Tenes un NullPointerException en la línea 25 del programa Datos.java.  Eso indica que estás llamando un método sobre una variable que tiene valor null. En el futuro por favor copia el error y agregalo como texto en lugar de usar una imagen.

Comment: No estoy seguo de como solucionarlo,entendi que llame a una variable(en este caso de tipo string) y no tiene datos, los datos de esa variable se introducen en un JTextField en la primera interfaz,  puse el codigo por si me podian ayudar.
Cualquier ayuda se agradece de verdad!:)